# Bigchain db search assets

Tags: bigchaindb

Hi for testing I have been using bigchain test servers. I have to search some asset so I do `searchAssets()` I have given asset keyword as `karthik@kliotech.com`. But it returned other results too, for example {

```
    "data": {
            "id": "138a65b3d20e9ad1f429e451a7235916161464d1b2f5ca6d3b90e02767dfbc46",
            "type": "mrofTestVote1",
            "vote": "like",
            "postedBy": "chen@test.com",
            "postedTime": 1525449076208
        },
        "id": "9eb8117115b363805e51f9e8f6b9c25e5811dbd448a017c27d3ff8dd666c1353"
    }
```

This also returned. But clearly it don't have karthik@kliotech.com. How search works in bigchain db? Can some one help me to figure this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This BigchainDB Blog post explains how it works with several examples:

https://blog.bigchaindb.com/introducing-queryable-assets-in-bigchaindb-v-1-0-adbe1b86e622

There's more about how full text search works in the MongoDB docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: Thank you Troy. It really helped me.